# C# post JSON data to REST API

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am new to REST API JSON but have been able to consume a few API with asp.net. Here is the problem I am currently facing.

I have been able to send JSON data to an API using this method.

```
public void PostData()
{
    string sName = sysName.Text;
    string sDescrip = sysDescrip.Text;
    var httpclient = new HttpClient();
    httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://33.248.292.99:8094/bizzdesk/sysconfig/api/");
    var sys = new Bizsys(){name= sName, description= sDescrip};
    httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("system", sys);
}
```

it work just fine.

Now I modify the code in order to accommodate more values thus:

```
var httpclient = new HttpClient();
// ArrayList paramList = new ArrayList();
httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://179.683.197.115:9091/tua-slte/api/organisations/");
var org = new Organisation() { id=1, name = "inno", abbreviation = "abx", type="school", sort = 7, isShow = true, createdBy=8, createdDate = "10/04/2017", editedBy = 11, editDate="11/04/2017"};
var bas = new Basic() { id=1, username = "inno", password = "123", firstName="Innocent", lastName="Ujata", email = "ea@bizz.co", mobile = "123456", photo="10201001", loginIp="127.0.0.1", loginDate="10/04/2017", locked=false, organisation = org, createdDate = "10/04/2017", editedBy = 11, editDate="11/04/2017", admin=true};
var org2 = new Organisation2() { id=1, name = "inno", abbreviation = "abx", type="school", sort = 7, isShow = true, createdBy=17, createdDate = "10/04/2017", editedBy = 09, editDate="11/04/2017"};
var hq = new HeadQuarter() { zonId=09, organisation = org2, zonCode = "123", zonName = "Abuja", zonAddress = "123456", zonCity = "Abuja", zonPostalCode = "120076", zonEmail = "answers", zonPhoneNumber = "0908765", zonFaxNumber = "1212", zonState = "FCT", createdBy=17, createdDate = "10/04/2017", editedBy = 11, editDate="11/04/2017", version=1};
var examp = new RootObject() {basic=bas, headQuarter=hq  };

var status = httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("register", examp);
return status;
```

It keep returning this:

```
Id = 19, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

I hard coded the data to see it work first before making it dynamic.

I have tried using await async method too the result is the same. 
all the questions and answers I have seen here are not similar.

What does that mean, and what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get your view. I am now having bad request after using private HttpStatusCode PostSomething()
 {
     ...
     var response = httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("register", examp).Result;
     return response.StatusCode;
 }    . How can I correct that pls

Comment: I am very sorry and will not repeat that again @halfer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an async method, but not awaiting it's results.

Change:

```
var status = httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("register", examp);
```

to

```
var status = await httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("register", examp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension method [PostAsJsonAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. You grab this task and see it's details. If you want to return status code of completed request, you should await for task completion and then grab status code from response message:

```
 private async Task<HttpStatusCode> PostSomethingAsync()
 {
     ...
     var response = await httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("register", examp);
     return response.StatusCode;
 }
```

Or you can synchronously wait for request completion:

```
 private HttpStatusCode PostSomething()
 {
     ...
     var response = httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("register", examp).Result;
     return response.StatusCode;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much...after using ur HttpStatusCode method above I got this response: status{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1. Can you provide me with further info at to why the Bad Request response please and any useful info to enable me post the data. Thanks you.

Comment: @Innoujata BadRequest means that you have sent request successfully, but you have sent wrong data. We cannot help you here, because we don't know what your API expects to get

Comment: Here is what the api expect to get:

Comment: api expect: {
 "basic":{                    
"username":"",                  
"password":"",
"email":"",                    
"mobile":"",                   
"organisation":{                        
"name":"",                        
"abbreviation":""                 
}
},             
 "headQuarter":{                   
 "zonName":"",                 
  "zonCode":"",                  
 "zonCity":"",                   
 "zonAddress":"",                 
 "zonEmail":"",                  
 "zonPhoneNumber":"",   
 "zonState":"",   
 "zonPostalCode":"",                
}
}

Comment: look at this and see what and I am getting wrong in my method pls.

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you are not awaiting the call like

```
var status = await httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("register", examp);
```

Or, use `ConfigureAwait()`

```
var status = httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("register", examp).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: @Rahul I got the same response awaitingActivation. but using this method private HttpStatusCode PostSomething()
 {
     ...
     var response = httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("register", examp).Result;
     return response.StatusCode;
 }    I got Bad request. can u please take a look again and let me know why the bad request? Thank you.